# I just want to read a txt file through pandas but getting a error of " Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 1 fields in line 20, saw 2"

Tags: python, pandas

[snapshot of my text file ]

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8BfYt.jpg)My text file looks like this

'199.72.81.55 - - [01/Jul/1995:00:00:01 -0400] "GET /history/apollo/ HTTP/1.0" 200 6245\nunicomp6.unicomp.net - - [01/Jul/1995:00:00:06 -0400] "GET /shuttle/countdown/ HTTP/1.0" 200 3985\n210.238.40.43 - - [01/Jul/1995:00:00:09 -0400] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 200 7074\n207.237.55.38 - - [01/Jul/1995:00:00:09 -0400] "GET /history/mercury/mercury.html HTTP/1.0" 200 1871\n219.156.97.22 - - [01/Jul/1995:00:00:09 -0400] "GET /shuttle/technology/images/sts_spec_6-small.gif HTTP/1.0" 200 47145\nxrf.koo.univie.ac.at - - [01/Jul/1995:00:00:09 -0400] "GET /ksc.html HTTP/1.0" 200 7071\n199.120.110.21 - - [01/Jul/1995:00:00:09 -0400] "GET /shuttle/missions/sts-73/mission-sts-73.html HTTP/1.0" 200 4085\nburger.letters.com - - [01/Jul/1995:00:00:11 -0400] "GET /shuttle/countdown/liftoff.html HTTP/1.0" 304 0\n199.120.110.21 - - [01/Jul/1995:00:00:11 -0400] "GET /shuttle/missions/sts-73/sts-73-patch-small.gif HTTP/1.0" 200 4179\n210.279.72.52 - - [01/Jul/1995:00:00:12 -0400] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 200 7074\n219.205.68.50 - - [01/Jul/1995:00:00:12 -0400] "GET /shuttle/missions/sts-70/images/KSC-95EC-1013.jpg HTTP/1.0" 20

first I tried

```
df  = pd.read_csv('log.txt', sep="\s+", dtype=str)
```

I got this error "Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 8 fields in line 306430, saw 9"

then I tried

```
path = r'C:\Users\HAS\Documents\log.txt'

with open(path, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
   reading_log = pd.read_table(f, sep='"', engine='python')\
                                           .dropna(how='all', axis=1)
```

then I was getting this error " 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x80 in position 7801: invalid start byte"

Ill appreciate help on this matter

Comment: does your file really has table formatted data? if not than mostly read methods of pandas will fail. if not then why don't you just read lines one by one.

Comment: The sample data you have posted is contains '\n' instead of new-line is this correct? You are getting error in line number 306430. I would suggest you post the data in lines 306425 - 306435 to recreate the problem. You could also try `low_memory=False` in read_csv function (this would make extremely slow).

Comment: @Sunnysinh Solanki its not perfectly tabular or table formatted but pretty consistent you can check the uploaded image, and did u mean that there is no method in pandas which will read file like that

Comment: @shanmuga    Im still getting that error. And I dont find anything unusual in  lines 306425 - 306435

Comment: If file is consistent then can you copy paste it in Excel and try to convert it to many columns through Data-->Text to Column option of Excel and then try to load that Excel.